# How to limit MySQL general_log file size?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to save general_log into a file and to avoid the file is too large.

MariaDB 10.3

```
#This is the settings I write in the my.cnf.
[mysqld]
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log = 1
```

I know there is way to set log_bin size or expire time, is there a way to set the general_log?
Or must I remove the file by crontab or manually.

Comment: Official Docs didn't specify and there are no pull requests, bugs, feature requests with that information. So, you are going to have to rotate manually.

Comment: Add a scheduled task to turn it off, delete the old backup, roll it to a backup, and turn it on again, scheduled as often as you need. Had mine running for ten years.

Comment: Why not store the log file in a table? See [log_output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output).. That one you can "rotate" without disableling `general_log_file` complete and mayby missing logs in the maintime... If you are going to export i advice you to creata a temporary table with the data from the table log that way you make it possible to delete a table log table with ine temporary table (key's) to make sure you only delete the exported data from the log...

Comment: It is not advisable to keep the general log on very long.  In many sites, it can threaten to fill up disk.

Comment: Well... there should be a way to limit in configuration... it's such a obvious thing... (i could not find it also...)

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem. It seems MySQL can't limit the size of the general.log file.

I finally use this command in a crontab to keep general.log last 20,000 lines :

```
$ tail -20000 /path/to/mysql/general.log | sponge /path/to/mysql/general.log
```

It's not perfect beaucause a request can be logged on mutiple lines.

If `sponge` is not available :

```
$ apt install moreutils
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware, official documents also does not specify any such configuration. We have configured it as part of startup script and cron tab for daily archival